# ASP.Net Server Side code, does it keep running after user logged out?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

To give this question context we have an ASP.Net MVC Project which requires you to be authenticated to use the system (typical saas product). The project includes an inactivity timer which will log the user out if they leave the screen alone for too long.  The project is an SPA type project and Web API is used to get/post relevant data.

I am currently having to develop a routine that archives a potentially huge amount of data and the process itself is fine. What I'm not sure of is once the process is started, a post is sent to web api and the server side code starts running, does it continue to run if the inactivity timeout occurs or the user logs out manually for some reason?

I assume it would but I don't like to rely on assumptions.

EDIT: For example
For below comments/answers. Screen will have a list of tickboxes for the data they wish to archive so is not a set list of data so this project does need to process the task.

The following code is on the client side when running (checks etc omitted and data variable contains all true/false values for ticks):

```
self.Running = true;
self.showProgress();

http.ajaxRequest("post", "/api/archive/runarchive", data)
   .done(function () {
        self.Running = false;
   })
   .fail(function () {
        self.Running = false;
        app.showMessage("You do not have permission to perform this action!");
});
```

For reference the showProgress function used to pick up progress to display on screen. This is also run when accessing the screen in case an archive process is still running it can be displayed:

```
self.showProgress = function () {
        http.ajaxRequest("get", "/api/archive/getarchiveprocess")
        .done(function (result) {
            if (result.ID == -1) {
                $("#progressBar").hide();
                $("#btnArchive").show();
                if (self.Running) setTimeout(self.showProgress, 2000);
                else app.showMessage("The Archive Process has finished.");  
            }
            else {
                $("#progressBar").show();
                $("#btnArchive").hide();
                $("#progressBarInner").width(result.Progress + '%');
                $("#progressBarInner").attr("data-original-title", result.Progress + '%');
                setTimeout(self.showProgress, 2000);
            }
        });
    };
```

Server Side:

```
[HttpPost]
public void RunArchive(dynamic data) 
{ 
    // Add table row entry for the archive process for reference and progress
    // Check each tick and update tables/fields etc
    // Code omitted as very long and not needed for example
    // table row for reference edited during checks for showProgress function
}
```

So basically I'm asking if the RunArchive() function on the controller will keep running until it's finished despite user logging off and being unauthenticated in some way. I'm aware any IIS, App Pool refresh etc would.

Comment: `but I don't like to rely on assumptions.` <= Neither do I. Please create an [mcve].

Comment: Good point @Igor. Please see edit.

Comment: @mjwills At the moment I'm still developing it and the current process finishes too quickly for a decent test, I'm trying to get the full knowledge in advance so I can adapt the process if required rather than developing it all first and it doesn't work.

Comment: What is the quickest way you can get a test up and running? _Hint - `Thread.Sleep`._

Comment: I'm part way through developing the function so was going to say I can't but I will create a quick test function with a Thread Sleep and log out manually as a test

Comment: Certainly keeps running until end of thread sleep but I will have to retest after development finished to be confident considering database connection, running functions etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like web api is the one doing the heavy work and once that starts it will continue to run regardless of what happens on the UI side of things.

This being said, there is a timeout for webapi requests that you can control in web.config.

You might want to consider another alternative. Whenever you're talking about heavy processing tasks, you're better offloading those to another service.

Your API is supposed to be responsive and accessible by your users and it needs to respond fast to allow for a better experience. If you get 100 users doing heavy work, your API will basically crumble.

The API could simply send commands to a queue of stuff that needs to be run and another service can pick them up and execute them. This keeps your API lightweight while the work is still being done.

You're talking about archiving which probably involves a database and there is no reason why you can't have something else do that job.

You could keep track of jobs in the database, you could build a table which holds statuses and once a job is done, the external service changes the status in the database and your UI can then show the result.

So the API could work like this:

1. add message to queue
2. add job details to db with status of "new" for example and a unique id which allows the queue item to be linked to this record.
3. Service B picks up the job from the queue and updates status in db to "running".
4. Job finishes and Service B updates status to "complete".
5. the UI reflects these statuses so the users know what's going on.

Something like this should would make for a better user experience I would think.

Feel free to change whatever doesn't make sense, it's a bit hard to give suggestions when you don't know the details of what needs to be done.

This Service B could be a windows service for example or whatever else you want that can do the job. The user permissions come into play in the beginning only, a work item would be added to the queue only if the user has the permission to initiate that. This gives you the certainty that only authorized jobs are added.
After that, Service B won't care about user permissions and will do the job to the end irrespective about users being logged in or not.

This is largely guess work at this point, but you should be able to get an idea of how to do this.

If you have more specific requirements you should add those to the initial question.

Comment: Thats essentially what I've done already (see edit). My main concern was as all the controllers require authentication would being unauthenticated cause it to stop in any way.

Comment: what I described has nothing to do with controllers, the work is being done by another service which doesn't care about the user being logged in or not. As such, the users getting logged out will not affect the work being done.

Comment: Ok, in my scenario an ASP.Net MVC Web Api Project, what service would you suggest is doing this. Baring in mind to run the process you must be an authenticated user with a specific permission.

Comment: added more details to my answer

Comment: Essentially the process runs through all relevant tables, and updates the rows accordingly and that's about it. Windows service would not be worthwhile as would be run very rarely but I will certainly move process itself from api controller as this makes sense thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Even if the process isn't killed by the user logging out, you also need to consider that IIS can recycle app pools, and by default is set to do so once a day, as well as on memory contention, either of which will kill your long running process.

I would highly recommend you check out [Hangfire.io](https://www.hangfire.io/), which is designed to help with long running processes in ASP.Net sites.